# convert hex to uint64_t with bash

Tags: bash

Is it possible to convert a hex string to uint64_t (or unsigned long long int) using bash script? The number is `FFFFFFFF3D4331BC`?

It seems that the `bc` command doesn't work with unsingned numbers?

Comment: Is `18446744070442398140` the correct answer?

Comment: bash doesn't have anything called `uint64_t`. Do you mean you want to convert a hex string to a decimal string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pure bash answer:

```
$ printf "%u\n" "0xFFFFFFFF3D4331BC"
18446744070442398140
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "main(){unsigned long long int i = 0xFFFFFFFF3D4331BC; printf(\"%llu\\n\", i);}" | gcc -x c - && ./a.out
```

I just did it with C.

EDIT:
answer

```
18446744070442398140
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash answer with `bc`:

```
$ echo "ibase=16; FFFFFFFF3D4331BC" | bc
18446744070442398140
```

You can also store it in a variable like this:

```
$ n=FFFFFFFF3D4331BC
$ echo "ibase=16; $n" | bc
18446744070442398140
```

Comment: Note that `bc` only works with uppercase hex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Perl answer:

```
perl -Mbigint -le 'print hex FFFFFFFF3D4331BC'
```

Output:

```
18446744070442398140
```